# How do I prevent Terminal.app from capturing Cmd/Ctrl/L?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, macos

Following the instructions at http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/handy-screen-locking-tips-for-mac/ I've set up a keyboard shortcut to lock my screen by hitting  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd>  . It works when the active window is Finder, or Notes, or Thunderbird, or ... well, most stuff.

There are a few applications where it doesn't though, Terminal being the most annoying. Terminal seems to capture it and treat it as ... well, I'm not sure what. It's not treating it the same as  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd> , or the same as  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd> .

It also happens in Chrome, although only on some pages - this 'ere page being one of them.

It worked just fine before I upgraded to El Capitan.

Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The trick, really, is to avoid common key-commands - which is why the article you refer to uses  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd> , as no OS X command would normally use only  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>  &  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  - they would always add  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  too, leaving you free to use  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  for anything you like.

If you insist on using  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd>  then you would have to add, *for each application that already uses it*, a new custom command so it will no longer trigger in preference to your own.

For example, for Terminal, where  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>L</kbd>  is Clear Screen

[image]

you would need to replace that in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts

[image]

and add a different, non-conflicting shortcut.

Comment: If I change it to Ctrl-Opt-L then it seems to work even less. It doesn't work in Terminal, or System Preferences, or Thunderbird, or Finder.